# ADF test on simulated stationary AR(1) processes fails to reject

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have series of logarithmic prices which seems to be mean reverting (`adf.test` from the "tseries" package in R gives `-3.6` value).
Based on that I create an AR(1) process

$$y_t=y_{t-1} + \mu + \lambda y_{t-1} + \sigma e_{t-1}$$

where $\mu$, $\sigma$ and $\lambda$ are derived from the historical prices (from regression coefficients; $\lambda$ is about `-0.02`).

Then I run simulation and create $n$ paths which I test for mean reversion and most of them do not get the $H_0$ rejected (no stationarity, no mean reversion).

I am confused with the results.
**Shouldn't the paths generated on the parameters of the mean reverting series be also mean reverting series at specified confidence level?**

Are the critical levels for the ADF Test the same in case of log prices? (My sample size was 500 and I used -2.57 for 10% confidence level)?

There are the parameters I get for the historical set

```
Call:
lm(formula = dy ~ y)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.091832 -0.009408  0.000525  0.009208  0.071752 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.074370   0.020870   3.563 0.000380
y           -0.020714   0.005811  -3.564 0.000379
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01599 on 1214 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01036,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.009542 
F-statistic:  12.7 on 1 and 1214 DF,  p-value: 0.0003789


R tseries package: 
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
data:  log(data$Adj.Close)
Dickey-Fuller = -3.6157, Lag order = 1, p-value = 0.03117
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Comment: ADF test is known to have low power. However, it is still confusing that it works for the original series but not its simulated copies. What test specification are you using, is it with drift? Could you include the output of the test for the original series? Also, $e_{t-1}$ should be replaced with $e_t$.

Comment: @ Richard Hardy $e_{t-1}$ is just a matter of notation in the code, because I create n random numbers $e_t=rnorm(n)$ while the main loop starts at k=2 , for (k in 2:(n+1) . I use ADF critical values for a model with a constant and no trend. $\Delta y_t=a_0+a_1y_{t-1}+ \epsilon_t$